# How to fit region of interest from an image to maintain aspect ratio using python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Esg.jpg)

As shown in the image I want to resize and scale the roi. I have the coordinates of ROI. Can someone help me to achieve this using python and opencv?

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/human-pose-comparison-and-action-scoring-using-deep-learning-opencv-python-c2bdf0ddecba

I am following this article if you scroll down you'll see a similar image and the author has tried explaining what he has done but I am unable to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide please a bit more informations about what  you want to achieve ?

Comment: Sure,
I am using posenet to define 17 key points in a body. If you see the above image then at the leftmost side is the original image and after some pre-processing, the image which we get has basically ROI has the main part. I have also updated the question and provided link from where I am following the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken 4 variations of the image which are the original, halved, big and stretched.

Here you go:

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("<your image>", 1) 


half = cv2.resize(image, (0, 0), fx = 0.1, fy = 0.1) 
bigger = cv2.resize(image, (1050, 1610)) 

stretch_near = cv2.resize(image, (780, 540), 
            interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST) 


Titles =["Original", "Bigger", "Half", "Stretched"] 
images =[image, bigger, half, stretch_near] 

for i in range(len(titles)): 
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1) 
    plt.title(Titles[i]) 
    plt.imshow(images[i]) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for code :)
But I am unable get this. In my case I have ROI coordinates and I want to fit that in the frame, for more clarity I have updated my question and have put the link of the article I am following.

Comment: If you closely study the article it talks about L2 normalization and I am not able to implement it.